# Rails code refactor in call method to handle map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just wondering is there any chance to get fresh eye on code below and make some code refactor?

```
def call
  inq_proc_ids = InquiryProcess.all.includes(inquiry_field_responses: :inquiry_field).select do |process|
    process.inquiry_field_responses.select do |inquiry_field_responses|
      inquiry_field_responses.inquiry_field.name == 'company_name'
    end.last&.value&.start_with?(company_filter)
  end.map(&:id)
  InquiryProcess.where(id: inq_proc_ids)
end
```

I think I should leave only InquiryProcess.where(id: inq_proc_ids) in my call method but I don't know how to handle with all these `.last&.value&.start_with?(company_filter)` and `.map(&:id)` stuff.

EDIT:

I was trying to split it to the new methods

```
def call
  InquiryProcess.where(id: inquiry_process_id)
end

private

attr_reader :company_filter, :inquiry_field_response

def inquiry_process_id
  InquiryProcess.all.includes(inquiry_field_responses: :inquiry_field).select do |process|
    process.inquiry_field_responses.select_company_name
  end.map(&:id)
end

def select_company_name
  select do |inquiry_field_responses|
    inquiry_field_responses.inquiry_field.name == 'company_name'
  end.last&.value&.start_with?(company_filter)
end
```

but I got an error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `select_company_name' for ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>):

Comment: I'd go to anyone who written that initially and ask why they decided to use `last` instead of `any?`. Is it possible (according to business rules) for one InquiryProcess to have mutliple `inquiry_field_responses` with name of `"company_name"`?

I'd assume in my answer there can only be one record as such due to lack of order information associated with the call to `last`

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not only hard to follow, but I remember we had a massive memory leak connected to ActiveReocrd caching when using precalculated ids in a query.

That said, I'd try to utilise the above within a single sql query:

```
def call
  id_select = InquiryProcess
    .joins(inquiry_field_responses: :inquiry_field)
    .where(inquire_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
    .where(InquiryField.arel_table[:value].matches("#{company_filter}%"))
    .select(:id)

  InquiryProcess.where(id: id_select)
end
```

Note that `id_select` is not an array of ids but ActiveRecord scope, the above will translate to following SQL:

```
SELECT "inquiry_processes".* 
  FROM "inquiry_processes" 
  WHERE "inquiry_processes"."id" IN (
    SELECT "inquiry_processes"."id"
      FROM "inquiry_processes"
      INNER JOIN ...
      WHERE ...
  )
```

And to answer another question - why do we query table by matching id to a result of another subquery on the same table? This is to avoid all sort of painful issues when you deal with an active record relation that has a join in it - e.g. it would affect all further `includes` statements, as the preloaded association would only include records matching the relation join conditions.

I really hope for you that this bit is quite well tested or you have someone who can verify validity of the behaviour.

Comment: You can use `ids` instead of `.select(:id)`, no?

Comment: @SebastianPalma - `ids` would return array of ids, which is what I'm trying to avoid. `select(:id)` return ActiveRecord relation, which will be inserted as a subquery.

Comment: Ok, so if I update your `call` to correspondent fields in db - ```id_select = InquiryProcess.joins(inquiry_field_responses: :inquiry_field).where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' }).where(InquiryField.arel_table[:value].matches("#{company_filter}%")).select(:id)``` I have an error ```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column inquiry_fields.value does not exist)``` which is true because value is not a column in db

Comment: When `where` receives an array it uses the `IN` clause instead using `=` @BroiSatse.

Comment: @SebastianPalma -Of course it is. And I'm trying to avoid it as such a query has issues with memory leak. It is always better to use single, same query rather than two queries where second relies on result of the other. It's usually faster as SQL optimizer is included, requires less memory as no interim values needs to be stored and it has no caching issues with memory leaks.

Comment: So, you prefer to pass a subquery to `IN` rather than passing directly the ids? @BroiSatse. I don't get your point about memory leaks and optimization.

Comment: Yes, the issue we hit was that if you calculate and use dynamic list of ids in your queary, rails will see each call as a new query and will attempt to cache it `with ActiveRecord::QueryCache` since the dynamic list of ids will often change, even for a medium size database that cache will exhaust your available memory, killing your application. In our case it meant forced server restart every two weeks (not much I know, but still annoying especially as it was affecting the business). @SebastianPalma

Comment: I don't know if we're referring to the same, but that will perform a single query, in any case (select, pluck or the whole ActiveRecord_Relation).

Comment: Well, no, because you firstly need to perform the query to obtain the list of ids. Using `pluck` or `ids` will firstly query the database to obtain the list of ids, and then insert that list into the second query (completely ruining cache). `select` on the other hand is not querying the database, but is used as a subquery in a single SQL query. This gives the database chance to optimise it and, since we always send the same query, only one caching record is stored in the memory.

Comment: @mr_muscle - Could you please add how `value` is defined?

Comment: @BroiSatse I think it comes from `gem attr_encrypted` - in model `InquiryFieldResponse` I've got `attr_encrypted :value, key: Base64.decode64(Rails.application.secrets.encryption_key)`